# Where do I go to report Unity 8 bugs?

Tags: unity, launchpad, bug-reporting, unity8

I'd love to point out some of the issues I'm having with Unity 8 so that they get solved sooner but where do I go to report them? I couldn't find anything on launchpad.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Unity 8 (unity8)` project under launchpad. There is also a `unity8-desktop-session` and some others. A lot of bugs seem to be [filed under](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity8) `unity8 (Ubuntu)`.